# class static member function chosen over global function with same name?

Tags: c++, static-methods

[Doubt originated from here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/macxhelp/v6v81/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.vacpp6m.doc/language/ref/clrc13cplr038.htm)

```
int g() {
   cout << "In function g()" << endl;
   return 0;
}

class X {
public:
  static int g() {
     cout << "In static member function X::g()" << endl;
     return 1;
  }
};

class Y: public X {
   public:
  static int i;
};

int Y::i = g();
```

initially I though that as symbol resolution happens from inner most scope to outer most scope, that is why x::g() would be called.
 but then I closely noticed the code

```
int Y::i = g();
```

how are we able to access X::g() without namescope? 
And scope in which this statement lies should be global, not Y:: or X:: , so symbol resolution should give global version of the function g()?

Comment: If you want the global function use `::g()`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Note: I think my earlier answer was wrong. Its not [Koenig Lookup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument-dependent_name_lookup) i.e Argument-dependent name lookup (ADL). So I deleted my (earlier) answer since I found the relevant section from the Standard which answers your question.

Your code is directly from the section §9.4/2 of the C++03 Standard.

> A static member may be referred to
>   directly in the scope of its class or
>   in the scope of a class derived
>   (clause 10) from its class; in this
>   case, the static member is referred to
>   as if a qualified-id expression was
>   used, with the nested-name-specifier
>   of the qualified-id naming the class
>   scope from which the static member is
>   referenced.

It then gives this example (which you've asked in the question)

```
[Example:

    int g();
    struct X {
        static int g();
    };
    struct Y : X {
        static int i;
    };
    int Y::i = g(); // equivalent to Y::g();

—end example]
```

It then says that in §9.4/3

> **If an unqualified-id (5.1) is used in
>   the definition of a static member**
>   following the member’s declarator-id,
>   and **name lookup (3.4.1) finds that the
>   unqualified-id refers to a static
>   member, enumerator, or nested type of
>   the member’s class (or of a base class
>   of the member’s class), the
>   unqualified-id is transformed into a
>   qualified-id expression in which the
>   nested-name-specifier names the class
>   scope from which the member is
>   referenced**.

Since that happens **only** in the *definition* of the static member, that means `Y::g()` is called ONLY in the **initialization**, not in **assignment**:

```
//definition-cum-initialization
int Y::i = g(); // equivalent to Y::g();
int main()
{
   //assignment 
   Y::i = g(); // does not equivalent to Y::g(); it calls global g()
}
```

See the output here : http://www.ideone.com/6KDMI

Lets consider another example:

```
struct B{};

B f();

namespace NS 
{
   struct A { static B b;};
   B f();
}

//Definition cum Initialization
B NS::A::b = f();  //calls NS::f()
B b = f();         //calls global f()

int main() 
{
   //Assignment
   NS::A::b = f(); //calls global f()
   b = f();        //calls global f()
}
```

See the complete demo here : http://www.ideone.com/53hoW

Comment: accepted & fully understood. In your previous answer I was thinking where are the arguments in here. anyway thanks for making me aware about Koenig Lookup (i never heard about it before), and of course answer to this question.

Answer (score 9):

This is because you use `int Y::i =...`, note the `Y::`. That's why, it actually looks for `g()` inside `Y`, which is `X::g()`, because `Y` derives `X`.

---

Addition: For example, if you put `int i = g();` after `int Y::i = g();`, there result would be:

```
In static member function X::g()
In function g()
```

---

<strike>**EDIT**: exactly - Argument-dependent name lookup. I couldn't remember how this is called at the beginning. Thanks Nawaz's answer (:</strike>

<strike>**EDIT2**: OK, Nawaz found the correct explanation, it's in the standard and it seems not to be "Argument-dependent name lookup". But the logic is still *absolutely* the same.</strike>

Comment: +1: even though Nawaz gave the rule name, he didn't clearly identified that the scope comes from `Y::i`.

Comment: @Kiril, @Nawaz: I was looking through n3242 and I cannot find where it is precised that Koenig Lookup applies here. **[class.static.data]** is silent about it. It seems strange (though it's obviously what's going on) since normally the result type does not participate into the lookup and overload resolution process. Would you know where it is ?

Comment: @Matthieu M. - I don't, sorry.

Comment: @Matthieu: You're right. `Koenig Lookup` doesn't apply here. I updated my answer with the correct reference from the Standard. Please see it.

Comment: Well, I've never read the Standard (shame on me! :D ), so it might not be "Argument-dependent name lookup", but the logic is still the same. Also, I connected this with Argument-dependent name lookup later. So, the answer is still correct, except the "Argument-dependent name lookup"

Comment: @Kiril and @Matthieu: I updated my answer with yet another interesting example which shows that `Y::g()` gets called only in *initialization*, **not** in *assignment*!!

Comment: @Kiril: No, this answer is wrong and the logic is NOT still the same. :P.... Saying that `This is because you use Y::` as answer, is not really an answer, given that it doesn't work if you do assignment : `Y::i = g()` DOES NOT CALL `Y::g()` :D

Comment: It's obvious that `Y::i = g()` does not call `Y::g()`  because it is not a valid syntax :D (if `i` is not static`) :D

Comment: @Kiril: That is valid syntax, that is called Assignment :P... see this : http://www.ideone.com/6KDMI

Comment: @Kiril: Now you need to add **"EDIT3"**. :D

Comment: @Nawaz - NO MORE EDITS :D:D Well, it would be assignment (only) when you assign something to a variable from the base class in a derived class :D OK, OK, you win :D You already got +1 from me at the very beginning (for the name, first )